# Better wording to represent " to show this in image..."

Tags: word-choice

I made a diagram that I want to show but I am confused with how to present it, like should I say " so this is how it looks in picture/diagram" or "to represent this graphically or in picture" or something like that. **Basically I want to say that - this is how it looks like in diagram** but I don't want to sound stupid or un-professional with wordings. So please help me

Comment: Edit your question to help us understand the context. Add an example sentence and leave a blank in it where you need us to fill it with a word/phrase.

Comment: "a node is denoted by 'n' and a node *icon*".

Comment: The diagram/line graph/bar chart (etc.) *illustrates* / *demonstrates* / *shows* / *represents*  OR This table *lists* ... OR The "thing" is *illustrated* / *demonstrated* / *shown* / *represented* by the following diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active construction: The diagram/line graph/bar chart (etc.) *illustrates* / *demonstrates* / *shows* / *represents*

If it were a table, then the verb *list* is appropriate.

OR use a passive construction.

The "thing being mentioned" is *illustrated* / *demonstrated* / *shown* / *represented* in the following diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps either "***To illustrate,..***" or, more focused on introducing or segueing to the visual image itself, "***Graphically**, [the thing] is represented as...*".

Answer (score 1):

**figure** /ˈfiɡyər/

> a diagram or illustrative drawing, especially in a book or magazine.
>   *"figure 1 shows an ignition circuit"* –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=figure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

"See figure 4." Often abbreviated as `fig.` on the drawing.

[image]

<sub>([source](http://3dprinters.3dsystems.com/figure4/))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Pictorial representation** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pictorial+representation)

> visual representation as by photography or painting

Or visual representation

**Illustration** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illustration)

> 2. something that serves to illustrate: as
>    a. an example or instance that helps make something clear
>    b. a picture or diagram that helps make something clear or attractive
>
> *"The illustration on page 30 shows the parts of an engine."*
> *"Illustration is the key to good communication."*

Comment: So, I should write - "that is visually representation by this..." ???

Comment: @AKC Give me the full sentence you want and I'll fill in the blank.

Comment: okay, 

the sentence : "node is denoted by ‘n’ and a node  ______ "

I want to fill that blank with something that says "a node looks like this *image*"

Comment: @AKC That doesn't help me understand your context even one bit. I want you to explain, not assume that I can read your mind. :)

Comment: sorry sorry, My net just stopped working for a minute, I was going to edit that, okay, so the sentence is :: "a node is denoted by 'n' and a node ____" and here in this blank I want to say how node is represented in pictures and this is what I wrote "a node is denoted by 'n' and a node is visually represented by..."

Comment: @AKC A node can be "represented visually." A node can have a "visual representation"

Comment: all right I will use-  a node is "visually represented" and then bla bla bla
also Mr.NVZ I did check your profile, are you an Artificial Intelligence professor? or any professional?

Comment: @AKC Glad to help you. :) I'm a fan of Marvel movies. "Artificial Intelligence" is something that I find amazing and equally terrifying. I'm a civil engineer.

Comment: "...the idea is graphically demonstrated in this illustration (or chart)..." "in visual terms, see Chart No. 1."

Comment: @pepper I thought of that, but "nodes" are not for graphs.

Comment: hey NVZ, please edit my question if you think its necessary

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the phrase "as follows".

> Attach part A to part B, and then press button C, as follows:
>
> < picture of the above >

Alternatively, "Blah blah blah as shown in the following diagram:".